# Google Script to scan gmail inbox and write to spreadsheet, too slow

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

Thanks in advance for your help.

I discovered Google Script recently and have been trying to write a script that scans the most recent 500 emails in  my inbox a few times a day, reviews the content of each email thread, and then compares the sender of each email, with email addresses in a spreadsheet. If a sender matches an email address in the spreadsheet, the script should enter "yes". Here is the code I have been able to come up with below. The problem I am having is that the code is very slow, and after it gets through about 100 rows of data, it times out.

I am wondering if an expert has an idea on where I am going wrong? I am sure my code is very flawed. However, I'm unable to figure out how to improve it.

```html
function getMail(){
    var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,500);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;  
    var numRows = 300;   // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 10); // 
    var data = dataRange.getValues();  
    var target = "Sales Email"
    for (var b = 0; b < data.length; ++b){
      var row = data[b];
      var leadEmail = row[4];
      for (var i = 0; i < thread.length; ++i){  
        var message = thread[i].getMessages();
        for(var c = 0; c < message.length; ++c){
          var currentMessage = message[c];
          var subject = currentMessage.getSubject();
          if(subject.indexOf(target) !== -1) {        
            var sender = currentMessage.getFrom().replace(/^.+<([^>]+)>$/, "$1");
            if(sender == leadEmail){
              sheet.getRange(startRow + b, 7).setValue("yes");
              SpreadsheetApp.flush();
              break;
             
            } 
          }
        
        }
    
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You are only breaking out of this loop: `for(var c = 0; c < message.length; ++c)` but you should break out of this one: `for (var i = 0; i < thread.length; ++i)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make the code a lot faster. It isn't necessary to fetch all messages from all threads over and over again for each row. Just fetch them once and write the sender into an array.

```
function getMail(){
  var senders = [],
      threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,500),
      target = "Sales Email";

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; ++i) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for(var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var currentMessage = messages[j],
          subject = currentMessage.getSubject(),
          sender = currentMessage.getFrom().replace(/^.+<([^>]+)>$/, "$1");
      if(subject.indexOf(target) !== -1) senders[sender] = true;
    }
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      startRow = 2,
      numRows = 300,
      dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 10),
      data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var b = 0; b < data.length; ++b) {
    var row = data[b],
        leadEmail = row[4];

    if(senders[leadEmail]) {
      sheet.getRange(startRow + b, 7).setValue("yes");
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne for this. I am going to test your update this morning and add my feedback. Again, thank you.

Comment: This is terrific. Works like a charm and is very very fast. I appreciate the feedback very much, and I definitely have learned something new. Thank you